# iOS UIKit / Core Foundation Exception

Tags: ios, uikit, appdelegate

I'm trying to get an app I've inherited up and running. Due to the fact it couldn't find the class it was trying to load, I changed the call in main.c from

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,  NSStringFromClass([TabBarTestAppDelegate class]));
```

to this:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I *think* the MainWindow.xib file is the one that is supposed to call the TabBarTestAppDelegate, which is why I'm trying this.

But, it's throws the following exception:

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x78878cd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00437946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0355ca97 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00437561 -[NSException raise] + 17
        3   Foundation                          0x02c2f10e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
        4   Foundation                          0x02b8b138 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
        5   Foundation                          0x02b8b0bd -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
        6   Foundation                          0x02bc09a6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 386
        7   UIKit                               0x01cb4649 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
        8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03572724 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
        9   CoreFoundation                      0x003715dc -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 316
        10  UIKit                               0x01cb310a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1775
        11  UIKit                               0x01cb4fa9 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 180
        12  UIKit                               0x0197de1b -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
        13  UIKit                               0x0197e134 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
        14  UIKit                               0x0197cadf -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1337
        15  UIKit                               0x019957d0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
        16  UIKit                               0x0197b81f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
        17  FrontBoardServices                  0x070399de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
        18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0703946f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
        19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0704b425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x0035b1c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x00350ad3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x0035092b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x0034fbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x0034f9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        25  UIKit                               0x0197b1e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
        26  UIKit                               0x0197e8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
        27  MyApp                              0x0005106c main + 76
        28  libdyld.dylib                       0x038b3ac9 start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm trying to figure out how this app was supposed to work when it was working. It has three targets - a base, then two others, which apparently incorporate the base. The TabBarTestAppDelegate.m is incorporated into "Build Phases" of the base, but it's the second "MyApp" which it's the app delegate for - and which maybe should be getting loaded from the xib file.

Was it a bad idea to change the call from main to not load the app delegate? What causes the above exception?

Comment: IIRC, the cause of this problem was there was a connection from the nib file to a non-existent field in the header, or vice-versa. It was a while ago, so I'm not positive